# Net Core Web App Exiting with no reason and no error

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-2019

I got  c# project made with .net boilerplate framework so I'm trying  to run it.Its builds ok, showing  cmd window with message Application shutting down then some db info messages then Aplication Started adress and in then end  The program '[pid] name.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).

My OS is W7, ide is VS2019.Project is on core 3.1.I have installed 5 and 3.1 too.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

**It was because of this**(I out log to file and ther are was additional informtion) :
*Failed to validate project name. Should not rename a project downloaded from aspnetzero.com. You can contact to info@aspnetzero.com if you are using a licensed product.
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.*